# Kerberos ticket creation with key tab and kinit not showing under Ticket Viewer app on macOS

Tags: macos, cron, kerberos

In order to perform some automation job through GitLab-CI, I have a Mac mini runner (macOS 10.14.6 Mojave).

The job requires an authenticated user through the mean of an active **Kerberos** ticket.

In order to have the ticket created and renewed automatically I made a small script as follows:

```sh
#/bin/bash

source ~/.zshrc

USER=<user>
DOMAIN=<domain>
PASSWORD=<password>
KEYTAB=<path/to/file.keytab>

# Remove keytab if present
if test -f "$KEYTAB"; then
  rm $KEYTAB
fi

# Create keytab file
/usr/sbin/ktutil --keytab=$KEYTAB add -p $USER@$DOMAIN -w $PASSWORD -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 -V 1

# Init ticket
/usr/bin/kinit --keytab=$KEYTAB -f $USER@$DOMAIN
```

When I run this script directly in **Terminal**, it successfully creates the keytab file and inits the ticket which shows up inside the **Ticket Viewer** app available through the **Keychain Access** app.

However when this script is run by the cron job, even though no error gets printed to the console, the ticket does not appear in the **Ticket Viewer** app.

Cron job for reference:

```sh
$ crontab -l

# Renew ticket every 4h
0 */4 * * * ~/renew_ticket.sh >> ~/renew_ticket.cron.log 2>&1
```

Any clue, why the ticket creation fails when running with cron?

---

Edit: 2021-08-13

I'm now using the "Kerberos Ticket Autorenewal" Mac app from Eugene Homyakov.

The app is available in the Mac App Store and you can find more info at https://hamstergene.github.io/macapps/ticket-renewer.

It's doing the job but I'm not really a fan of relying on a third party app, as it is not open source and could stop working with a new release of macOS if it's not maintained.

I also contacted Brad Howes after reading his article at http://keystrokecountdown.com/articles/kerberos.

He suggested that cron jobs are not running in the same environment as the regular user and that it may cause issues with the renewal of the ticket.

He also pointed out 2 utilities worth considering:

- `k5start` https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start
- `krenew` https://linux.die.net/man/1/krenew

I'll have a look at those and report back any progress here.